# Using Spatial Join in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I am having an issue when trying to use the spatial join tool in ArcGIS.
I have 2 datasets:

1. Tennessee Counties
2. Tennessee Protected Areas

I want to join these two datasets so that I have the total area of protected areas within each county in Tennessee.

I have Protected Areas as the target feature, and Tennessee Counties as the join feature. When I attempt a one to one intersect join some counties have way more area of protected area than the area of the county.

What merge rules should I utilize to sum the total area of protected areas within each county?

Comment: Try switching the two inputs: your goal is to have counties with a sum of their protected areas.  The layer you want to get out at the end should be target.  Your merge rule will be SUM on the area field from the protected areas.

Comment: Do you have any Protected Areas that overlap more than one county?

Comment: Yes, most Protected Areas overlap multiple counties. I want the total area of Protected Areas within each county.

Comment: Then I suggest performing an Intersect, recalculate the areas and then summarize your areas by county.